# J2ME Gtalk Connection over XMPP fails

Tags: java-me, xmpp, connector

I am developing J2ME app that connect to GTalk. I am using WTK2.5.2.
 Here is my code sample,

```
      StreamConnection connection = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(
                  "socket://gmail.com:5222", Connector.READ_WRITE);
      InputStream inStream  = connection.openInputStream();
      int i = inStream.read();//returns -1
```

It doesn't get connected on port 5222 port.(with 5222 port is open in firewall) 
When i connect with 443 port, it connects well but the input stream is not read correctly. While reading the stream, first read character return -1.

Please Help Me!